# generate multiple qr code in the same webpage

Tags: php, qr-code

I need to generate mulitple qr code in the same webpage.

Which echo in a table,one row one qr code, and it is generated by calling echo 'img src = "generateqrcode.php"'.
Also I need to do some checking before printing each row the data and qr code.

However I found that the generated qr code were overwritten by the last one. Why this happened?

generateqrcode.php

```
  session_start();
  $key = $_SESSION['key'];
  $link = TARGET_LINK.$key;
  QRcode::png($link,false,"L",10,0);
```

A.php

```
$row=1;
while($row <=1){
echo '<table>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row;
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
$sql = GETSECTIONSQL;
if(!($qids = get_records_sql($query))){
            $qids = array();
         }
 foreach($qids as $qid){ 

        $qrsec = $qid->section;
if($section == $qrsec){
$sql2 = GETLINKSEQUENCESQL;
if(!($viewids = get_records_sql($query))){
            $viewids = array();
         }
foreach($viewids as $viewid){
$vid = $viewid->sequence;
session_start();
$_SESSION['vid'] = $vid;
echo '<td>';
echo '<a class="fancybox" href="generateqrcode.php">';
echo '<img src="generateqrcode.php"/></a>';
echo '</td>';
}
}
}
echo '</table>';
$row++;
}
```

New

A.php

```
  foreach($viewids as $viewid){
  $vid = $viewid->sequence;
  echo '<td>';
  echo '<a class="fancybox" href="generateqrcode.php">';
  echo '<img src="generateqrcode.php?id=$vid"/></a>';
  echo '</td>';
```

}

generateqrcode.php

```
  $id = $_GET['id'];
$link = TARGET_LINK.$id;
QRcode::png($link,false,"L",10,0);
```

Comment: Please can you expand on this a bit? Including your code, and a screenshot or example of this problem will help us help you.

Comment: No, this is not generally a problem with QR codes on web sites; it's perfectly possible to have more than one. It's a problem with *your specific code.*

Comment: Code provide !THANKYOU

Comment: @Hecksa I cannot hv the screenshot can my ac level.... but show you the code already

Answer (score 1):

Well, all your images are linking to the exact same "image" `generateqrcode.php`. Of course they're all going to look the same. Since your session can only store one value at a time, you cannot transport any ids unique per image in the session. You should make unique links to unique images:

```
<img src="generateqrcode.php?id=1234567">
```

Then use `$_GET['id']` when generating the image instead of the session value.

Comment: I got another problem, Why $_GET['id'] cant get the value? I shown you the code.